# Get values from a yaml file into pom.xml

Tags: maven, yaml, pom.xml

Ive been searching for an answer to this and I see people trying to get values from a pom.xml into a yml file but not the other way around.

Say I have plugin.yml

```
main: main
name: CustomPlugin
version: 0.03
author: Me
```

How would I get the value of "version" into my pom.xml so that I don't have to update version in both the yml and pom.xml. Note I DO NOT want to go from pom.xml to yml.

I'm thinking something like this but I don't know enough about maven and pom's to be sure:
pom.xml

```
<property file="src/plugin.yml" prefix="plugin"/>
```

and then use ${plugin.version}?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `plugin.yml` file into `src/main/resources` and configure in [Maven filter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: is there anyway to get the values from plugin.yml without moving it into resources? The whole plugin is a shared git, and some people are using maven to autobuild, others are using Ant to auto build and i dont wanna change around the base folder structure.

Comment: Just change the above directory...But I recommend to follow the conventions in Maven...

Comment: how would i then reference the version from the yaml file? sorry I dont know xml or pom at all

Comment: I don't know why need the `plugin.yml` file and what purpose the `plugin.yml` has...so I can't help here....If you don't know pom.xml you have to learn first what it's purpose...

Comment: The project is a minecraft plugin thus spigot requires plugin.yml. I do know what pom is for I just dont know it's lingo like how to call properties and varaibles.

Comment: This answer does not address the question in any way.