# pom.xml how to use variables from a .yml file

Tags: java, maven, properties, yaml

I have a YAML file in my resources package that looks like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: ${DB_HOST:localhost}:${DB_PORT:5432}/${DB_NAME:my_database}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME:postgres}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD:postgres}
```

I want to use these values in my `pom.xml` file, so that I don't have to hardcode them in there. How can I do it? At the moment, my editor complains (highlights them in red) if I just try referencing them:

```
<jdbc>
            <driver>${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}</driver>
            <url>${spring.datasource.database-url}</url>
            <user>${spring.datasource.database-user}</user>
            <password>${spring.datasource.database-password}</password>
          </jdbc>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get values from a yaml file into pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861456/get-values-from-a-yaml-file-into-pom-xml)

Comment: I had a look at that question but it doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: What about going the other way around and use the properties in pom file and let Maven filter them into the yml file? Furthermore what kind of Application is this? An spring boot app ?

Comment: @khmarbaise not sure what you mean 100%. Yes it is a spring boot app

Comment: please have a look at : https://github.com/ozimov/yaml-properties-maven-plugin, it claims to offer exactly this functionality (, try & report your xperience;)